# Installing a plugin on a premium site

Tags: plugins, installation

Hi i'm trying to install a plugin on my site but i'm constantly asked to upgrade to business plan. Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you on a WordPress.com site or a self-hosted WordPress.org site?

Comment: This site is for people developing/programming with WordPress with questions about WP development. ( as installed from wordpress.org ). What you're describing is the business plan of the wordpress.com hosting service. You should contact wordpress.com support, or migrate to another host so you can use normal WordPress